# Pause background service in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have an application that occasionally speaks via the systems text to speech(TTS) system, but if there's a background service (like an audiobook, or music stream) running at the same time they overlap.
I would like to pause the media, play my TTS, then unpause the media. I've looked, but can't find any solutions.

I believe if I were to play actual audio from my app, it would pause the media until my playback was complete (if I understand what I've found correctly). But TTS doesn't seem to have the same affect. The speech is totally dynamic, so I can't just record all the options.

Using the latest Xamarin.Forms, I've looked into all the media nuget packages I could find, and they all seem pretty centered on controlling media from files.

My only potential thought (I don't like it), is to maybe play an empty audio file while the TTS is running. But would like a more elegant solution if it exists.

(I don't care about iOS at the moment, so if it's an android only solution, I'm okay with it. And if it's native (java/kotlin), I can convert/incorporate it.)

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is managing audio focus: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-audio#managing-audio-focus

I'm not sure how to best incorporate this with TTS, but hopefully that points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with rbonestell said, you can use `DependencyService` and `AudioFocus` to achieve it, when you record the audio, you can create interface in PCL.

```
   public interface IControl
{
   void StopBackgroundMusic();
}
```

When you record the audio, you can executed the `DependencyService` with following code.

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IControl>().StopBackgroundMusic();
       //record the audio
    }
```

In android folder, you can create a `StopMusicService` to achieve that.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(StopMusicService))]
namespace TTSDemo.Droid
{
  public  class StopMusicService : IControl
    {
        AudioManager audioMan;
        AudioManager.IOnAudioFocusChangeListener listener;


        public void StopBackgroundMusic()
        {

            audioMan = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
            listener = new MyAudioListener(this);
            var ret = audioMan.RequestAudioFocus(listener, Stream.Music, AudioFocus.Gain);

        }
    }

    internal class MyAudioListener :Java.Lang.Object, AudioManager.IOnAudioFocusChangeListener
    {
        private StopMusicService stopMusicService;

        public MyAudioListener(StopMusicService stopMusicService)
        {
            this.stopMusicService = stopMusicService;
        }

        public void OnAudioFocusChange([GeneratedEnum] AudioFocus focusChange)
        {
          //  throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I plan on looking at this more closely later tonight, but do you know off hand if the AudioManager would allow me to then start the audio playing again from the original application? The goal of this functionality is for the TTS to tell me how far/fast I've gone in the last little bit, but if I'm listening to a book/song, it just speaks over the other audio. I'd like to pause it, do TTS, then unpause the audio. It *looks* like this solution only handles the pause? (once again, I'll look more closely later tonight, and I appreciate the answer!)

Comment: From this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287289/how-do-you-return-audio-focus-to-previously-playing-apps), it looks like it's possible to relinquish focus, which I'm hoping means starting things up again from the previous audio manager. Will attempt to go this route in conjunction with yours. Thanks again for your answer! If I can get it to work, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Leon Lu - MSFT, I was able to go in the right direction. I took his implementation (which has some deprecated calls to the Android API), and updated it for what I needed.

I'll be doing a little more work making sure it's stable and functional. I'll also see if I can clean it up a little too. But here's what works on my first test:

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MediaService))]
namespace ...Droid.Services
{
    public class MediaService : IMediaService
        public async Task PauseBackgroundMusicForTask(Func<Task> onFocusGranted)
        {
            var manager = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
            var builder = new AudioFocusRequestClass.Builder(AudioFocus.GainTransientMayDuck);
            var focusRequest = builder.Build();
            var ret = manager.RequestAudioFocus(focusRequest);
            if (ret == AudioFocusRequest.Granted)
            {
                await onFocusGranted?.Invoke();
                manager.AbandonAudioFocusRequest(focusRequest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```