# How to make possible to listen to another App song/audio

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am leaning Xamarin,

I have build a quick app that read audio effect file (mp3/wav).

**My problem :**

When I start the App while I was listened music ( spotify/deezer ) the musique stops because the app has started.

So, I would like to be able to listen to music ( spotify/deezer ) and use my app.

My audio C# class in Android looks like this :

```
public class MyAudioOutput : IAudioServiceOutput
{
public void GetAudioSetting()
{

    var audioManager = (Android.Media.AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AudioService);
    audioManager.Mode = Mode.Normal;
    audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true;
}
}
```

My Audio C# classe in IOS looks like this :

```
public class MyAudioOutput : IAudioServiceOutput
{
public void GetAudioSetting()
{
    var session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
    session.OverrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker, out NSError error);
    session.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
    session.SetActive(true);

    
}
}
```

My interface in  Xamarin Forms shared :

```
public interface IAudioServiceOutput
{
    void GetAudioSetting();
}
```

In my Xamarin forms cs file  , I use the function this way :

```
ISimpleAudioPlayer AudioPlayerGood;

void InitMyAudio()
{

    string filenamegood = "Question.Good_Answer.mp3";


    using (Stream streamGood = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filenamegood))
    {
        AudioPlayerGood = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        AudioPlayerGood.Load(streamGood);
    }


}

void OnPlayAnswerSong(bool goodanswer)
{
    if (goodanswer == true)
    {
        AudioPlayerGood.Play();
    }

    else if (goodanswer == false)
    {
        AudioPlayerWrong.Play();
    }
}
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus

Comment: @Jason pease do you have a code example

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can refer to the following thread:[Pause background service in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60461679/pause-background-service-in-xamarin-forms)

The implementation on android platform is as follows:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(StopMusicService))]
namespace TTSDemo.Droid
{
  public  class StopMusicService : IControl
    {
        AudioManager audioMan;
        AudioManager.IOnAudioFocusChangeListener listener;


        public void StopBackgroundMusic()
        {

            audioMan = (AudioManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
            listener = new MyAudioListener(this);
            var ret = audioMan.RequestAudioFocus(listener, Stream.Music, AudioFocus.Gain);

        }
    }

    internal class MyAudioListener :Java.Lang.Object, AudioManager.IOnAudioFocusChangeListener
    {
        private StopMusicService stopMusicService;

        public MyAudioListener(StopMusicService stopMusicService)
        {
            this.stopMusicService = stopMusicService;
        }

        public void OnAudioFocusChange([GeneratedEnum] AudioFocus focusChange)
        {
          //  throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And you can also check the updated part code by Nieminen included in above link.